# What is difference between @FXML , @FXMLController and @ViewNode?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

In DataFX & JavaFX there's many annotation do same thing. *At least that's what I think*. My question is when to use each one of these annotation?

- @FXML
- @FXMLController
- @ViewNode

Answer (score 1):

Let me describe each of these annotations and how they are relevant while using DataFX.

- @FXML - This annotation enables an FXMLLoader to inject values defined in an FXML file into references in the controller class. It is a part of JavaFX.
- @FXMLController - This annotations is used by the controller class to define its FXML file that contains the layout of the view.
- @ViewNode and @ViewController - @ViewNode was introduced in DataFX as a successor to @FXML. With its introduction, @FXMLController was renamed to @ViewController. The entire commit can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/datafx/datafx/commits/a45ebf011a67f81b2194a9790153d4c95b6b8d07).

[Here](http://www.guigarage.com/2015/01/datafx-tutorial-6/) is another good source of information.